# Need help on developing SCD query in SQL/SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new in Sql Server

I need to build query on below requirement. Please help me achieve it.

Data available in table

```
Store | Product | Price | FromDate   | ToDate
S1    | P1      | 50    | 1-Feb-2016 | 1-Feb-2016
S1    | P1      | 150   | 2-Feb-2016 | NULL
S1    | P2      | 20    | 1-Feb-2016 | NULL
S1    | P3      | 30    | 1-Feb-2016 | 1-Feb-2016
```

Input from user : date Consider 3-Feb-2016

Required Output :

```
Store | Product | Price | Date
S1    | P1      | 50    | 1-Feb-2016
S1    | P1      | 150   | 2-Feb-2016
S1    | P1      | 150   | 3-Feb-2016
S1    | P2      | 20    | 1-Feb-2016
S1    | P2      | 20    | 2-Feb-2016
S1    | P2      | 20    | 3-Feb-2016
S1    | P3      | 30    | 1-Feb-2016
```

Regards,

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. What is the user input supposed to do?

Comment: Here user input restrict output upto which date data has to be repeated. for example If user input date is 4-feb-2016 then 2 more lines added in required output. 1 for Product P1 and One for Product P2 with data as Date on 3 Feb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script shows how you can implement the query

instead of @data you need to use your table. I just put this to run my solution

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (
Store varchar(10),
Product varchar(10),
Price float,
FromDate date,
ToDate date
)

INSERT INTO @data (Store, Product, Price, FromDate, ToDate)
VALUES
('S1', 'P1', 50, '2016-01-01', '2016-01-01'),
('S1', 'P1', 150, '2016-01-02', NULL),
('S1', 'P2', 20, '2016-01-01', NULL),
('S1', 'P3', 30, '2016-01-01', '2016-01-01')
```

This is the user input date:

```
DECLARE @userInput date = '2016-01-03'
```

You stuff the all available dates between minimum date and user input date in a table variable

```
DECLARE @allDates TABLE (dt date)

DECLARE @minDate date = (SELECT MIN(FromDate) FROM @data)
WHILE @minDate <= @userInput
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @allDates (dt) VALUES (@minDate)
    SET @minDate = DATEADD(d, 1, @minDate)
END
```

And this is the final query

```
SELECT t.Store, t.Product, t.Price, dt AS [Date]
from @data t LEFT JOIN @allDates ad ON ad.dt = t.FromDate OR ad.dt = t.ToDate OR (t.ToDate IS NULL AND ad.dt>= t.FromDate)
ORDER BY t.Store, t.Product, dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem requires to create date sequence and SQL Server does not have "ready to use" solution for that, but you can find solutin in other threads.
Here is your solution with only 5 days range:

```
DECLARE @sequence TABLE (number int)
INSERT INTO @sequence(number) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)

DECLARE @DateToConsider date = '20160203'
SELECT SP.Store, SP.Product, SP.Price, DATEADD(d, s.number, SP.FromDate) [Date]
(SP.ToDate, @DateToCOnsider))
FROM StoreProduct SP
    INNER JOIN @sequence S ON number <= DATEDIFF(d, SP.FromDate, ISNULL(SP.ToDate, @DateToCOnsider))
ORDER BY Store, Product, [Date]
```

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I am looking for.